# ASP.NET Core MVC Authenticate User to Azure AD then create JWT Bearer Token to call Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, openid, openid-connect

I am building an *ASP.NET Core Web API* that will be secured by *Azure AD* (secured via `app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication`)

I am building an *ASP.NET Core MVC* controller (secured by `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication`) which calls that **WebAPI**.

I am trying to implement the authentication flow as described in the *OpenID Connect Basic Client Implementer*’s guide.

The sample code I find for this pattern.

one example is here:

> /active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs)

is using **.NET** (not **.NET Core**) with **OWIN**.

You use the `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` method and call `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsynch` to get the token you’ll use in your request to the WebAPI.

When I try to build the analogous pattern in *ASP.NET Core MVC*, I see the following:

1. When I configure MVC’s app. `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` with defaults, then I can log into the system, but I don’t get an authorization code back.  The Event that fires for me is the `OnTokenValidated` event instead of the `AuthorizationCodeReceived` event shown above. It has an identity and a token, which is great.
2. When I configure MVC’s app. `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` `response-type = “code”`, then I get a code back, the `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` event fires, but I get no identity back.

[My azure application manifest was set up for `oauth2AllowImplicitFlow: true`. In this case, the user authentication and token generation are compressed into a single step, which is not as secure as I need, so I set to false.]

After further investigation, I learned that the *Asp.Net Core* infrastructure is designed to handle multiple separate authentication middleware entries, and that

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer / JwtBearerHandler.cs

is coded to throw a 'not allowed' error if you try to use the `SignIn` workflow with a *JwtBearer* configuration.

Therefore, it looks like I will have to follow that multiple middle ware approach.  One cookie-based middleware for the login, and one bearer-token-based middleware for the bearer token to access services linked to this App. 
(instead of the model from the **OWIN** sample where the call the to service is done after receiving the authentication code)

This feature (multiple authentication middlewares) is described in https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme.html

Does anyone have an example for this? Or am I still thinking about this wrong?

Comment: Do you have anything to share on the topic? I am trying to do almost the same and I cant find any good sample for this topic using ASP.Net Core.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to obtain also identity along with code you should specify this with your request => `response_type=code+id_token`.

After retrieving both I hope you are going to be able to set cookie for your user and also to request client authentication and token.

I am pretty sure exact scenario is described in [Authorize access to web applications using OpenID Connect and Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-openid-connect-code).